# webform control to iterate X times through a template

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Here is my problem. I need to display an html table with 9 cells in each row, how can I do it without writing every cell's html code ?
I'd need something like that :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <asp:repeater runat="server" datasource="[0..9]">
     <itemtemplate>
       <td><%# Eval("value") %></td>
     </itemtemplate>
    </asp:repeater>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there any built-in asp.net control ? I don't want to build some html code in my code-behind.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There sure is, [Enumerable.Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range.aspx).  In your case it'll be

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 9)
```

You can then retrieve the current enumerator value [like so](http://forums.asp.net/t/1328545.aspx)

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```

Comment: How do I get the value inside the itemtemplate ?